# Spring HTTP client timeout - webservice call - misresponse

Tags: spring, http, timeout, client

I have an unknown App consuming my Spring webservices.

The app set a timeout to every webservice calls.

The server regardless of the app timeout keeps processing.

Is there a risk of any other webservice call in receiving a misresponse (the response to the timed out webservice call)? How does Spring manages this? Doesn't HTTP protocol take care of this, given that each connection channel is open for a particular call to webservice and if broken there shouldn't be possible to retrieve the response?

Comment: The timeout the client application is setting - is an HTTP client timeout after expiring the clientside HTTP client should close the streams (input/output) and the timeout should be treated as a failure (by default). You should implement idempotent requests to your serverside to allow the clientside to retry the failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you should try to make all possible HTTP requests to your web server to be idempotent. It means that the client side has to be able to retry the failed request without new possible errors due to the inability to know the previous (timeout) request results.

The client side should handle the HTTP client timeouts himself and (by default) should treat the timeout error as a failure. Your clientside may repeat the request later and the server side should be able to handle the same request. 

The solutions may vary for different tasks depending on complexity (from an INSERT statement to the database or scheduling a new CRON job avoiding duplication).

Comment: Considering an app using Jsch SSH tunneling, that invokes a remote webservice .  Aren't these connections to remote server dedicated connections? Meaning, if a channel is open for that specific call how does spring and HTTP protocol manage this information and this connection in order to know that that response should be sent to a specific channel?